# Binding multivalued column's data into combo box via vba ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a table as follows

[image]

Where the BranchIds column is a multivalued column referering the ids of the branches table.
Some how i need to bind the id and its related value in a combo box residing in another access forms as follows
[image]

The permission table contains the data of which user is allowed to access which branch.
I am unable to bind the branches from the perimssion table to the combo box in my another form.

> The code i am trying. Got from MSDN after a length search..

```
Sub BindBranches()
   Me.comboBranchIds.RowSourceType = "Value List"

   Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset
   Dim childRS As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()

   ' Open a Recordset for the Tasks table.
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT BranchIds FROM Permissions WHERE UserId = " & Forms!NavigationForm!txtSession.Value)
   rs.MoveFirst

   Do Until rs.EOF
      ' Print the name of the task to the Immediate window.
      'Debug.Print rs!TaskName.Value

      ' Open a Recordset for the multivalued field.
      Set childRS = rs!BranchIds.Value

         ' Exit the loop if the multivalued field contains no records.
         Do Until childRS.EOF
             childRS.MoveFirst

             ' Loop through the records in the child recordset.
             Do Until childRS.EOF
                 ' Print the owner(s) of the task to the Immediate
                 ' window.
                 'Debug.Print Chr(0), childRS!Value.Value
                 Me.comboBranchIds.AddItem Item:=childRS!Value.Value
                 'Me.comboBranchIds.RowSource = "SELECT BranchName FROM Branches WHERE ID = " + childRS!Value.Value
                 childRS.MoveNext
             Loop
         Loop
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MultiValue field has little to do with a value list.

Just use the *RowSource* property of the MultiValue field, like:

```
SELECT [TableName].[FieldName] FROM [TableName] ORDER BY [Id];
```

as the *RowSource* property for your combobox.

Having a filter:

```
SELECT [TableName].[FieldName] 
FROM [TableName] 
WHERE UserId = [Forms]![NavigationForm]![txtSession]
ORDER BY [Id];
```

or modify the SQL by code to, say:

```
SELECT [TableName].[FieldName] 
FROM [TableName] 
WHERE UserId = 466
ORDER BY [Id];
```

Applying a revised SQL will automatically requery the combobox.

Comment: First of all thanks for responding in urgency. Where do i include the criteria / where clause. I mean i need the branch ids of a particular user id from the permission table.

Comment: The query is just how it appears by default. For your new combobox, you can add/include any filter or other sorting the usual way.

Comment: Hi @Gustav. i used Query to come up with a solution. can u tell how to pass a parameter to the query in combox row source

Comment: combo does not get populated

Comment: Do i need to explicitly cast the UserId value as int ?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake was using txtSession.Text. Now removed that extra word: "Text". Thanks. Its working Perfectly